# Random pick items of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following code in my index.html page

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="words.js"></script>
    <script>
        var words = [];
        window.onload = function () {
            words = getwords();
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

And in word.js file

```
function getwords() {
    var block = [];
    var keyword = ['HELLO', 'CYCLE', 'APPLE', 'albatross', 'platform', 'OPERA', 'COURT', 'HOUSE', 'NEWEST', 'AEROPLANE', 'SCIENTIST', 'CORRIDOR', 'BUTTERFLY'.
        'MUSICAL', ' AUSTRALIA', 'XYLOPHONE', 'TAPESTRY', 'DREAM', 'NEEDLE', 'GIRAFFE'
    ];

    var index = [];
    for (var p = 0; p < keyword.length; p++) {
        index[p] = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (keyword.length - 1));
        for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if ((words[j] !== keyword[x]) && (index[x] !== 1)) {
                block[i] = keyword[x];
                index[x] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return block;
}
```

I want my getwords function to return any 8 words from keyword array everytime it is called in the onload and it should get stored in words array and those words shouldnt be repaeted next time. However my code doesn't work. May I know my mistake? Please help!

I tried

```
function getwords(){
var block = [], index =[];
var rem = keyword.length -1;
for(var p=0 ;p <(rem+1) ;p++)
{
index[p]=0;
}

 for(var i = 0; i < rem; ++i) keys.push(i);
 for(var i=0; i<8 ;i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * rem);
    while(index[x]===1)
    {
     x = parseInt(Math.random() * rem);
    }
    block.push(keyword[x]);
    index[x]=1;
    }

    return block;
    }
```

Still gives some same words on second call.

Comment: `for(var p=0 ;p< keyword.length ;p++)` low performance approach.

Comment: Specify what you mean by `my code doesn't work`, what isn't working?

Comment: When you say `those words shouldn't be repeated next time`, do you mean that if they reload the page, they shouldn't get the same list?

Comment: You got typos in your code. The `.` in the array should be `,` and `<body>` should be `</body>`.

Comment: calling array.length will iterates the array and have a O(array.length) linear time complexity.

Comment: and your random algorithm also takes O(8*N) complexity, not a good way, compare with my solution, your random taking procedure can be improved.

Comment: Oh, that doesn't matter at all in this case, I just want to notice that you can keep a better, not to compare with the length of an array in the for condition phrase.

Comment: Ok, thanks to notice that, I'm not sure about it now, but maybe the older web browser approach actually does this. And from some other materials I have read recommends to use `for(var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; --i)` better than `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)`

Comment: It is outdated, you are right, thank you.  @user2864740

Comment: Do you mean the words should not be repeated in the *returned set of words* or that the words should not be repeated *when the page is reloaded*? What happens if the page is reloaded several times, such that all the words are "used up"?

Comment: This code isn't giving any output by what I mean not working

Comment: I mean no single word should appear more than once at one reload. it can appear the next time but i.e all 8 words should be different at a time

Comment: it will be better if 8 words come at 1st time, next 8 later without repeat.

Answer (score 1):

A small mistake has cost you this problem ...

While storing the indexes in the index array you are using `index[p] = 0;`

But which should be

```
for(var p = 0; p < keyword.length; p++) {
    index[p] = p;
}
```

here is the [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b6e85/)

Comment: This doesn't work. I ran it a few times and got "dogma,dogma".

Comment: @user2864740 the problem is related to the non uniqueness of the Random Number being generated .. .. ...

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a nicer approach. Tested to be OK, have a try.

```
var keyword=[
    'HELLO', 'CYCLE', 'APPLE', 'albatross', 'platform',
    'OPERA', 'COURT', 'HOUSE', 'NEWEST', 'AEROPLANE',
    'SCIENTIST', 'CORRIDOR', 'BUTTERFLY', 'MUSICAL',
    'AUSTRALIA', 'XYLOPHONE', 'TAPESTRY', 'DREAM',
    'NEEDLE', 'GIRAFFE'];

var keys = [];
for(var i = 0; i < keyword.length; ++i) keys.push(i);

function getwords(count){
    var block = [];
    // first.
    // pick and remove [count] times. Becareful when keys goes empty.
    while(count > 0 && keys.length > 0) {
        var x = parseInt(Math.random() * keys.length);
        block.push(keyword[keys[x]]);
        keys[x] = keys[keys.length-1];
        keys.pop();
        --count;
    }
    return block;
}

console.log(getwords(8));
console.log(getwords(8));
console.log(getwords(8));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: @fish_ball .. ur solution worked. but the problem is I need the next set of 8 words when the function is called next. That is why I created the index array for marking/unmarking. i.e the js page should work as a datbase that always gives the next 8 words when called

Comment: That's simple, If you don't need it next time, just keep the keys array, I change the code and please check again.

Answer (score -1):

What you mean by "doesn't work"? What shows the console?

'BUTTERFLY'.'MUSICAL'. There's a dot instead of a comma.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not any answer..
you should better make a comment.